# number_format multiple vars at once in php

Tags: php

I have the following script

```
$a = 434343434343;
$b = $a *3;
$c = $a * 6;

print $a;
print $b;
print $c;
```

I want all three variables to be returned using the `number_format($var)` syntax. The three vars are being printed in various parts of an html template. What is the best way to do this for all three vars at once? Should I add these vars to an array and number_format the array?

The best that I can come up with is the following:

```
$a = 434343434343;
$b = $a *3;
$c = $a * 6;

$a = number_format($a);
$b = number_format($b);
$c = number_format($c);
print $a;
print $b;
print $c;
```

Is that preferred?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `$c = number_format($c, 2, '.', '');` or something at the top ?

Comment: what format do you want?  maybe put an example in your question.

Comment: hi all, i've updated the question with what i've come up with so far. trying to see if this is "best" practice or not...

Answer (score 2):

Put those numbers inside an array and format the array, it's faster.

```
$numbers = array();
$numbers['a'] = 434343434343;
$numbers['b'] = $numbers['a'] * 3;
$numbers['c'] = $numbers['a'] * 6;

foreach($numbers as $key => $val)
{
    $numbers[$key] = number_format($val);
}
```

by the way, if you NEED the values as variables, you can extract them:

```
extract($numbers); //creates the variables $a, $b, $c
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
```

You can see it in action [right here](http://viper-7.com/P2MMti).

Comment: i do not agree. i've posted an answer that i think is better.

Comment: Your solution just reduces one step, but my solution is better since it will automatically number_format everything. Let's suppose you had 1000 variables, formatting them would be faster than typing it 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a much better solution.

```
$a = number_format(434343434343);
$b = number_format($a *3);
$c = number_format($a * 6);

//$a = number_format($a);
//$b = number_format($b);
//$c = number_format($c);

//output
print $a;
print $b;
print $c;
```